# Unknown Exception/Error in JavaFX FXML 2.2

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, javafx

I am using *NetBeans 7.3.1* and *JavaFX 2.2.*

I am getting an error which says just '2' (not like `NullPointerException`, etc). When I change some 2-d Array values then error is some other number.

StackTrace :

> Executing com.javafx.main.Main from (my project path).jar using platform D:\Java\jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java
>
> 2 this is my error. sometimes 6,5 ,etc

```
file:/(my project path).jar!/<project name>/SelectionWindow.fxml

at <project name>.SelectionWindowController.attachBrandImagesAndNamesToTiles(SelectionWindowController.java:92)
  at <project name>.SelectionWindowController.initialize(SelectionWindowController.java:33)

  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2152) 
  at ..... all the trailing trace
```

Explain me this error and how to solve it.

Comment: can you provide the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Well, seeing the exception is thrown from this line:

```
brandNames[i][j] = new Label(DataInterface.getBrandName(i, j));
```

It may be reasonable to assume you have your array elements out of range, causing it to throw an `OutOfBoundsException 2` if for example you tried to reach element 2 from the array but for example it only has 1 element.

Without your full stack trace it is hard to say for sure though.

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to say.  The stack trace shows the error on line 92, which is this:

```
brandNames[i][j] = new Label(DataInterface.getBrandName(i, j));
```

The javafx.scene.control.Label constructor doesn't appear to throw any exceptions (see http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Label.html#Label%28java.lang.String%29).  I would say

- Put a try/catch block around the entire inner loop.
- In the catch statement, use reflection to find out what exactly the class type of the exception is (post back if you don't know how, and I'll write the code for you)
- And then also write out the message from the caught exception.